# Nuxt - how to prevent redirecting to home page after login

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

Hi we are using nuxt and came to nuxt-auth.

In a gist, our use case seems to be different from what nuxt-auth thinks is right and I was not able to tune nuxt-auth to do what I want, hence asking for help.

My use case: After the signup endpoint responds with 200, we want to show a `/refer` page or a `ReferPage` component.

Nuxt-auth behavior: Once logged in, or once `setUser` is called, nuxt-auth will redirects immediately to 'home' page, which is in our site `/app`.

Would appreciate any help for modifying this behavior. The idea is something like `redirectWhenLoggedIn: false` (an imaginary property), which prevents immediate redirects after login.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of these might help:

1. You can create your own scheme which is authentication logic
2. Or you can use a scheme and in scheme option set the 'redirect_uri' option to your need

Here is a link about this option from documentation:

[Redirect uri nuxt auth documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/oauth2.html#redirect-uri)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your redirects in nuxt.config.js via the auth options api:

```
auth: {
  redirect:false
}
```

*Each redirect path can be disabled by setting to false. Also you can disable all redirects by setting redirect to false*

see: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options/